# Cypress - click on element when not disabled

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an anchor in an Angular app which is disabled until the page content loads, which takes some time.
Is there any way to click it only after it stops being disabled?

I tried with:

```
const myItems = cy.get('whatever-selectors');
myItems.contains('some text', {timeout: 10000}).should('not.be.disabled').click();
```

This doesn't work.

The documentation states that Cypress will retry clicking until the `should` condition is fulfilled or the timeout is exceeded, but it fails after less than half the time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that ,,should" is an assertion. To trigger a click event, cypress has to find an element first.

For this case usually worth to use a pseudo selector like

```
cy.get('whatever-selectors:not([disabled])').click();
```

In case of the loading takes more time than the default configuration you can alter the line like

```
cy.get('whatever-selectors:not([disabled])', { timeout: 10000 }).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `timeout: 10000` with `cy.get()`

```
cy.get('whatever-selectors', {
    timeout: 20000
}).should('be.enabled').click();
```

Comment: I get the same result, sadly.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try increasing the timeout this time.

Comment: It definitely doesn't have that kind of delay. If I put cy.wait(5000) before trynig it, it works. Does it make a difference that I'm doing it in `Cypress.Commands.add(...)` ?

Comment: can you add your html dom ?

Comment: Sadly, I can't. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Maybe after the colleague that has code on their machine return from vacation (they just finished work) I could write up a version without proprietary names and such. I'll definitely let you know in the comment in case you are still open to help out :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario, where a button was disabled till some data was returned from a network request. Pseudo-selectors didn't work for me, I solved it by [intercepting](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) the call that was disabling the button, and waiting for it to complete before proceeding:

```
cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '**/whatever/content',
}).as('getContent');
cy.wait('@getContent');

cy.get('whatever-selectors').click();
```

The intercept-wait block was placed right after the action that triggered the call.